# Unity Joystick Bug, it goes to the same place on the firt touch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, joystick

I'm trying to make a simple game where a ball moves, but there's a problem. When I press the joystick the player moves correctly,but at every time I touch the joystick it first go in the bottom-left position and not where I just clicked. The position in the screen is where it goes even if I touch another place
[image]

Here's the script of the joystick:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class VirtualJoystick : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{

private Image bgImg;
private Image joystickImg;
private Vector3 inputVector;

private void Start()
{
    bgImg = GetComponent<Image>();
    joystickImg = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
}

public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped)
{
    Vector2 pos;
    if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(bgImg.rectTransform, ped.position, ped.pressEventCamera, out pos))
    {
        pos.x = (pos.x / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
        pos.y = (pos.y / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);

        inputVector = new Vector3(pos.x * 2 + 1, 0, pos.y * 2 - 1);
        inputVector = (inputVector.magnitude > 1.0f) ? inputVector.normalized : inputVector;

        // Move joystickImg
        joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition =
            new Vector3(inputVector.x * bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 3
                , inputVector.z * (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 3));

    }
}

public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped)
{
    OnDrag(ped);
}

public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped)
{
    inputVector = Vector3.zero;
    joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
}

public float Horizontal()
{
    if (inputVector.x != 0)
        return inputVector.x;
    else
        return Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
}

public float Vertical()
{
    if (inputVector.x != 0)
        return inputVector.z;
    else
        return Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at the [Joystick Pack](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/joystick-pack-107631) for some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice in `OnDrag()` you set `pos.y` using `bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x` instead of `bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y`.

And in `Vertical()` you are also checking `inputVector.x` instead of `inputVector.z`.

These most likely won't fix the bug but they are good fixes to make.

What will work is removing the offset in

```
inputVector = new Vector3(pos.x * 2 + 1, 0, pos.y * 2 - 1);
```

Change this to

```
inputVector = new Vector3(pos.x * 2, 0, pos.y * 2);
```

removing the +1 and -1, and that should fix it!

Comment: Thanks you so much, it worked fine for me, and thanks even for the other corrections